# Change text box color in Adobe InDesign CC

Tags: adobe-indesign

When modifying text in Adobe InDesign CC, a text box with a bright yellow outline appears around the text in question. This text box and its handles are extremely hard to see on a white background, especially on a high resolution 5K display.

It is possible to change the colors of guides to whatever you’d prefer By going to Preferences > Guides and Pasteboard and customizing. However, the text box outline guide color (which seems to me to be the most important one to customize) isn‘t present anywhere on this list.

Does anyone know how to modify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click the layer where the text is and change the selecting frame color from yellow to the color of your preference.

[image: layer colors]